Modifying a prop in a child component?
I have a parent component that passes in an error as a prop.
Inside my child component I want to modify the error prop. This is not allowed.
So, I can create a local copy...
const error = props.error;

But when the parent updates error the child does not receive the update in the local var.
How to address this.
Note, I wish to create a copy in the child component so I can modify it in the child component.

The way this needs to be implemented depends on your case, consider explaining it. Why does a child need a copy? Basically it's either localError.value = props.error in a watcher, or not using local state at all and updating it through two-way binding

How exactly and for what do you want to change the prop?

Have you checked defineModel ?

I recommend using a computed if you want to have a copy of the prop from the parent. A regular JS variable will not be reactive, unfortunately.
This question is still relevant for Vue3 I think. There is no new hacky way to do it either because it is seen as an anti-pattern anyway.
Another cleaner approach would be to use a watcher or a method to mutate a local ref state in the child, that way you do not touch the prop, just have a local dependency in the child based on the prop passed from the parent.

PS: more context regarding the why.
TLDR is mostly that you should keep it straightforward between the parent and child so that it's easy to debug.
It is meanwhile marked as Use with Caution in the style guide, hence you could just ignore that rule and live your life on the edge if you are fine with doing it in a non-Vue way.

I think you can use callback function.
So you make a function to be able to edit your error prop in your parent component.
Then pass it as prop into your child component with your error prop.
In this case, I think you can handle your error variable of your parent component directly in your child component.
If you can provide example, I can answer detail.

I think that OP specifically wants to do things in the child component here. But otherwise yes, a regular parent/child (with props/emits) approach to propagate the flow up and down is still preferred.
